# How to get coordinates of a point on a path in Illustrator with JS?

Tags: javascript, bezier, curve, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

What I'm trying to get is a JS function that would return coordinates of some specific point on a path that is not an anchor point. It'd be perfect if a point could be described as just a relative position on a length of a path — for example inputting 0.25 would get me coordinates of a point that divides a path into one fourth and three fourths.

The only way I know I can get any point on a curved path in Illustrator is calculating bezier curves manually between each two path points, and I guess I can determine on which part of a path a requested point lies and then work from here, but maybe there's an easier way?

Comment: What have you already looked at/tried? (also note that AI can't actually do javascript, it uses ActionScript3, so you're in for a world of fun if you want to write code to do even seemingly simple things. No APIs introduced into JS after 1998 for you. Or me. Or anyone)

Comment: As a quick dirty solution I'd try to make a copy of the path, to divide up every segment of the path up into a lot of small segments about the same length (I believe it can be done). And then to calculate which of these points is closest to the given relative position. Say, if there will be 100 points on the path, and the position is .25, you need take coordinates of 25th point.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans For now I don't have any better idea then what I described in the second part of the question. But that solution requires a lot of math and fiddling with anchor points, so I didn't implement it yet in hopes of finding a better solution. Basically implementing it like that would mean that AI scripting doesn't provide any way to "visualize" a curve (aside from manually calculating bezier curves).

Comment: @YuriKhristich I thought of that, and I even found someone else's script that does basically that (divides each segment into equal parts), but for my purposes that would either be very inaccurate or very slow. Basically I'm trying to recreate "blend" tool (which afaik I can't access with a script) with different parameters and for a different purpose. That means that sometimes I'd need to put up to a few thousands of individual points on path with high precision (or "blend effect" would tear), that would mean dividing path into what feels like up to a million of parts.

Comment: As far as I can tell you can handle blends (and many other things like meshes, raster elements, etc) via C++ API. It's a shame that Illustrator's developers made JS/VBA API so limited.

Comment: @ТарасМукин "Basically implementing it like that would mean that AI scripting doesn't provide any way to "visualize" a curve (aside from manually calculating bezier curves" welcome to scripting in Adobe products. It's 20 years behind everyone else. In fact, because it's so bad, you might have far better results asking in the Adobe community forum for illustrator, because _someone_ no doubt needed it at some point, and they're not going to be a Stackoverflow user.